# How to load certificates in tls connection using gcdasyncsocket

Tags: ios, objective-c, gcdasyncsocket, tls1.2

I am working on an iPhone app that works on GcdAsyncSocket and creates TLS connection, I generate RSA keys and CSR using those and sent CSR to server, server responded with a certificate and some other certificate that is like public key to it. Now I need to make another TLS connection with server and send private key nd 2 certificates back to it. I have gone through many posts but didn't find any way how to achieve this.
If anyone could help and with some code that would be great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution for it. Can you please post some code how you was loading the certificate and sending it to server. I am running in to the problem of loading the certificate.

Answer (score -1):

After spending good amount of time, I was able to resolve the issues using open SSL library. I used following code

```
+(PKCS12*)convertToP12Certificate:(NSString*)certificate
        certificateChain:(NSArray*)certificateChain
 publicCertificate:(NSString*) publicCertificate
           andPrivateKey:(NSString*)privateKey
{
//we create a x509 from primary certificate which goes as a single entity when creating p12
const char *cert_chars = [certificate cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

BIO *buffer = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_puts(buffer, cert_chars);

X509 *cert;
cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(buffer, NULL, 0, NULL);
if (cert == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"error");
}
X509_print_fp(stdout, cert);



//create a evp from private key which goes as a separate entity while creating p12
const char *privateKey_chars = [privateKey cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

BIO *privateKeyBuffer = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_puts(privateKeyBuffer, privateKey_chars);

EVP_PKEY *evp;
evp =PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(privateKeyBuffer, NULL, NULL, "Enc Key");
if (evp == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"error");
}
if (!X509_check_private_key(cert, evp))
{
    NSLog(@"PK error");
}

PKCS12 *p12;

SSLeay_add_all_algorithms();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();




const char *cert_chars2 = [publicCertificate cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

BIO *buffer2= BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_puts(buffer2, cert_chars2);

X509 *cert2;
cert2 = PEM_read_bio_X509(buffer2, NULL, 0, NULL);
if (cert2 == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"error");
}
X509_print_fp(stdout, cert2);


STACK_OF(X509) *sk = sk_X509_new_null();
sk_X509_push(sk, cert2);




for(NSString * tempCertificate in certificateChain)
{
    const char *cert_chars3 = [tempCertificate cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    BIO *buffer3= BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_puts(buffer3, cert_chars3);

    X509 *cert3;
    cert3 = PEM_read_bio_X509(buffer3, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (cert3 == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
    X509_print_fp(stdout, cert3);
    sk_X509_push(sk, cert3);

}



p12 = PKCS12_create(P12_Password, P12_Name, evp, cert, sk, 0,0,0,0,0);

return p12;
}



+(NSArray*)getCertificateChainForCertificate:(NSString*)certificate
                        certificateChain:(NSArray*)certificateChain
                       publicCertificate:(NSString*) publicCertificate
                           andPrivateKey:(NSString*)privateKey
{



PKCS12 *p12 = [CryptoHelper convertToP12Certificate:certificate
                                   certificateChain:certificateChain
                            publicCertificate: publicCertificate
                                      andPrivateKey:privateKey];
NSData *PKCS12Data = [CryptoHelper convertP12ToData:p12];



NSArray *certs = nil;

SecIdentityRef identityRef = nil;

CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data;
CFStringRef password = CFSTR(P12_Password);
const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
const void *values[] = { password };
CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, options, &items);

CFRelease(options);
CFRelease(password);
if (securityError == errSecSuccess)
{

    NSLog(@"Success opening p12 certificate. Items: %ld", CFArrayGetCount(items));
    CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
    identityRef = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict, kSecImportItemIdentity);

    if(certificateChain)
    {
        CFArrayRef certificates = (CFArrayRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,kSecImportItemCertChain);

        // There are 3 items in array when we retrieve certChain and for TLS connection cert
        SecIdentityRef chainIdentity = (SecIdentityRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(certificates,1);

        certs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(__bridge id)identityRef,(__bridge id)chainIdentity, nil];
    }
    else
    {
        certs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(__bridge id)identityRef, nil];
    }

} else
{

    NSLog(@"Error opening Certificate.");
}


return certs;

}
```

We can pass this array to TLS connection for key `GCDAsyncSocketSSLCertificates`.